# devTools remote debug device port forwarding other than localhost

Tags: android, google-chrome, developer-tools, usb-debugging

I need to connect from one android device (galaxy TAB) to my developing PC via (USB) -> chrome://inspect/#devices -> port forwarding

**In other words I want to open in my galaxy TAB a chrome page with one of mi sites hosted in my PC**

*In my pc I have multiple virtual host eg: localhost, site1, site2 ... all with SSL port 443 and self signed certificates*

I have also edited in my PC C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts so each site have 127.0.0.1 like IP

**In summary: from my PC I can access all these sites without any problem**

---

*Now I need to connect those sites on my PC from my galaxy TAB via USB*

---

**If I have tried** port forwarding in devTools 8080 -> localhost:443
**Everything OK**. I can see my PC localhost on galaxy TAB

But if I try port forwarding in devTools 8080 -> site1:443

> I got `ERR_NET_TIMEOUT` and never connect to site1, site2 etc

I have also removed temporally all htacces files to avoid others interferences ( so in localhost I can see INDEX OF files but in others virtual domains NO)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like that:

1. I have configured a proxy connexion in my android device
   see : [debugging-local-server](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/) find `Configure proxy settings on your device` on the anterior link

Then I found another problem (seem to be a bug ... only for SSL)
access to localhost still to be OK but site1, site2 etc return `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` even if I put a simple index.php with `echo "OK";`

Then I made this workaround:

2. in `httpd-ssl.conf` I have changed `DocumentRoot` from localhost directory to `my/path/to/site1`

after that when I put `https://localhost:8080` in my android device for debugging I got content from `site1` instead of the old `localhost`

Take care also if your script depend on absolute links like `https://site1/something_else` you must change all from `site1` to `localhost` or use `htaccess` with `mod_rewrite`

**Conclusion**

So even if this workaround it work, still a bug with proxy and SSL. In this case I have removed proxy configuration (from step 1) because debugging localhost with SSL work without needing a proxy configuration

Sorry for my English!